# update_attributes with included array one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How in rails, do you call `update_attributes()` on a active record object, and have it create appropriate rows in `one-to-many` associated table based on an array param.

Is this possible? Or do I need to manually loop through that param's array and insert the many rows manually via `create_record()` etc?

To be clear, I might have users table with 1-to-many addresses. I want to call users.update_attributes() passing in the user details to be updated, but also provide an array of addresses mapping to the addresses table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `User` model:

```
model User
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

now user can be created with this set of params

```
params = { user: {
  name: 'Dimitri', address_attributes: [
    { country: 'Georgia', city: 'Abasha', line: '35 Kacharava Str.' },
    { country: 'USA', city: 'Los Angeles', line: '10 Infinite Loop' },
    { country: '', _destroy: '1' } # this will be ignored
 ]
}}

User.create(params[:user])
```

more details can be found from [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).